# How does overload resolution work with variadic template arguments and a non template argument derived type

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, overload-resolution, function-templates

I'm trying to create a overload for a function with variadic template arguments for a type and all its possible derivates.

Naively i tried with just one overload and the base class as the first parameter but this doesn't work for derived types. A third overload with a concept or an enable_if can make it work for derived types (and then the first overload wouldn't be needed anymore) but i don't understand why the overload with the base type (the first overload) isn't considered in the overload resolution when called with a derived type.

Can someone explain this?

Here's the code ([live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5YEs54E8v)):

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {};
struct B : public A {};

template<class... Types>
void func(Types... args)
{
    std::cout << "1";
}
template<class... Types>
void func(const A& a, Types... args)
{
    std::cout << "2";
}
// why is this needed to cover the derived class?
// with this function enabled, the output is "3" and without "1"
#if 1
template<typename dA, class... Types>
requires std::derived_from<dA, A>
void func(const dA& a, Types... args)
{
    std::cout << "3";
}
#endif

int main()
{
    func(B{});
}
```

To maybe make the question clearer; why does [this](https://godbolt.org/z/Thf7TjYfo) print `1` and not `3` like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/zY8nr6MK9) does?

Comment: So basically you're asking why `func(B{})` chooses `3` instead of `1` when both overloads are present. So you can just *remove the other unnecessary calls `func(A{})` and `func(1)` because in both cases the output is the same for both of those calls.*

Comment: @user12002570 I'm wondering why `func(B{})` chooses `"1"` if the second overload isn't present.

Comment: I think I have the answer to that. But can you then remove the other two calls as their output doesn't change and it would be better to answer for one call in one post.

Comment: Walter E. Brown did a [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NIDEjY5ywqU) on this very subject at CppCon 2018.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling `func(Derived{})` without the last overload, `1` gets printed instead of `2` because the implicit conversion sequence when calling it is better.
Implicit conversion sequences are more important than which function template is more specialized.

When adding the overload with the `std::derived_from` constraint, `1` and `3` have equally good implicit conversion sequences, and `3` is chosen because it is more specialized.

### `1` is chosen based on implicit conversion sequences

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Base {};
struct Derived : public Base {};

void func(auto) { std::cout << "1"; }

void func(const Base& a) { std::cout << "2"; }

int main() {
    func(Derived{}); // prints 1
}
```

Intuitively, `func(const Base&)` is a better match because it isn't a template, or because it's intuitively "more specialized" in some other way.

However, `func(auto)` is selected. The way overload resolution (see [[over.match.general]](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.general)) works is that

1. all candidates are tested for viability, which disqualifies some
2. the best candidate is chosen based on various criteria ([[over.match.best.general]](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best.general))

   - first and foremost, based on which implicit conversion sequence is best ([[over.match.best.general] p2.1](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best.general#2.1))

A prvalue of type `Derived` is converted to `const Base&` through a **derived-to-base** conversion ([[over.ics.ref] p1](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.ref#1), [[over.best.ics.general] p7](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.best.ics.general#7)), which has the rank [Conversion](https://eel.is/c++draft/tab:over.ics.scs), whereas `Derived{} -> auto` is an [Exact Match](https://eel.is/c++draft/tab:over.ics.scs).
Thefore, it's better to call `func(auto)`.

### `3` is chosen based on most specialized function templates

> ```cpp
> template<typename dA, class... Types>
> requires std::derived_from<dA, A>
> void func(const dA& a, Types... args)
> ```

This case is different.
Since `a` binds to any `const dA`, it binds to `Derived` directly without any derived-to-base conversion.
There is an [Exact Match](https://eel.is/c++draft/tab:over.ics.scs) conversion for `1` and `3`.

`3` is more specialized because it has a constraint `std::derived_from` and is chosen as the best candidate ([[over.match.best.general] p2.5](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best.general#2.5)).